# How to restart an assignment after a long break?

Tags: masters, philosophy, homework

I usually work on an assignment in a continuous flow. I study Philosophy, so I have to read and write a little every day.

I have recently shifted place and it took a whole two weeks gap. Now that I'm back on the desk, I don't know where to start from. My already half-done assignment looks gibberish to me.

It's frustrating and very difficult for me to get past that feeling and start over again. Any helpful suggestions on what I can do about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, if it looks like gibberish, then starting over is probably the wisest option. It will get you back in the flow. Put the first "version" aside and just begin again from the description you have of the task.

I'll note that some people doing important work re-write from scratch, maybe more than once, to get what they think is a better result each time.